# Problem with T4 Templates

Tags: .net, t4

I have the following code and it is giving related to curly braces and stuff.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>

namespace MyProject.Entities 
{   
    public class     
    {
        <#
        string connectionString = 
            "Server=localhost;Database=GridViewGuy;Trusted_Connection=true"; 
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
        conn.Open(); 
        System.Data.DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("TABLES"); 

        foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in schema.Rows) 
        { 

        #> 

        public class <#= row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() #>            


        {

        }               

        } 

    }   

}
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it is not compiling is because you don't have a corresponding closing brace for the foreach block inside `<# #>` tags. You need to make the following change:

```
foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in schema.Rows)                 
{                 
#>                 
  public class <#= row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()#> 
  {                
  } 
<#
  } //this was missing.
#>
```

Additionally, keep in mind that your code will create a class with no name followed by a list of nested classes with the names of your tables. Like this:

```
public class
{
  public class Table1
  {
  }

  public class Table2
  {
  }
  //... and so on..
}
```

This may not be what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should install the Tangible T4 editor plugin for Visual Studio.  It will give you matching brace highlighting that makes this sort of thing really easy to figure out.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/1a6c4fb2-7908-4721-92b3-61f2cee92294

Comment: Tangible is cool until you realize the intellisense is slow and spotty at best, and you can't insert a breakpoint into the template.

Answer (score 2):

In your first block, you start a code block

```
            foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in schema.Rows) 
            { 

            #>
```

but never terminate it.  Somewhere below you need this:

```
            <# } #>
```

*edit* - it looks like it would be the closing curly brace just below the nested class definition